# The `.data` argument of `add_column()` must have unique names

Tags: r, tibble

I want to relegate the rownames to a column labeled `Sample`. All the rownames are unique.

```
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "Sample")
```

Traceback:

```
Error:
! The `.data` argument of `add_column()` must have unique names as of tibble
  3.0.0.
ℹ Use `.name_repair = "minimal"`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(pstage = c("stage ii", "stage i", "stage ii", 
"stage ii", "stage i"), age = c("53", "71", "67", "80", "60"), 
    malignancy_type = c("", "", "", "", ""), days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), days_to_last_follow_up = c("207.0", 
    "2298.0", "", "2861.0", "1731.0"), race = c("white", "white", 
    "white", "white", "white"), gender = c("male", "male", "male", 
    "male", "male"), ethnicity = c("not hispanic or latino", 
    "not hispanic or latino", "not hispanic or latino", "not hispanic or latino", 
    "not hispanic or latino"), vital_status = c("0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0"), survival = c("lts", "lts", "non-lts", "lts", "lts"
    ), samID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A"), clust = c(1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2), subtype = c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a"), samID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A"), clust = c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a"
    ), stage = c("2", "1", "2", "2", "1")), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests you have duplicate names in the data namely "samID" and "clust". Tibbles do not allow having duplicate column names, you may clean up the names using `janitor::clean_names()` and then use `rownames_to_column` function.

```
df |>
  janitor::clean_names() |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Sample")
```

This updates the second instance of "samID" and "clust" to "sam_id_2" and "clust_2" respectively.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative might be and keeping the original names:

```
df <- cbind("Sample" = row.names(df), `row.names<-`(df, NULL))
```

If needed this can be converted to a `tibble` even with duplicated names.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(df, .name_repair = "minimal")

tibble::is_tibble(df)
#[1] TRUE

names(df)
# [1] "pstage"                              
# [2] "age"                                 
# [3] "malignancy_type"                     
# [4] "days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis"
# [5] "days_to_last_follow_up"              
# [6] "race"                                
# [7] "gender"                              
# [8] "ethnicity"                           
# [9] "vital_status"                        
#[10] "survival"                            
#[11] "samID"                               
#[12] "clust"                               
#[13] "subtype"                             
#[14] "samID"                               
#[15] "clust"                               
#[16] "stage"
```

Or (thanks to @moodymudskipper !)

```
tibble::tibble(Sample = row.names(df), df, .name_repair = "minimal")
```

Comment: or `tibble::tibble(df, Sample = row.names(df), .name_repair = "minimal")`